# Thread safe token handling in .NET

Tags: c#, .net

I have Web API.
Authorization is made via token from 3rd party API.
If request comes i check is token set -> if not, get it, set and use.
If response is 401 i need to try refresh token and then call API.

How to make it thread safe way and make other requests wait until failed one retries?

Request -> if token set -> use token, make request -> if response 401 -> try refresh token, make request one more time -> if failed, die.

All threads should use same token and not try to refresh it when some other thread already tries to do it.

Comment: You should Probably use a single instance class (Singleton Pattern) and set a field when you are waiting for a token.

Comment: Yes, i have this in place and locking field. 
But this not works ok for retry mechanism.
Thinking about auto refresh when getting token and seeing it is expired.
Then lock method until it is refreshed. In this case 401 will be avoided.

Comment: That's not how a http call works.

Comment: When locked, other threads waits. How to understand your message?

Comment: The way i have this setted is I have a class that handles the entire API, the class handles the token and the requests, so from the controller I call this class and this class makes a first attempt to call the API, if it fails, it calls a method to refresh the token, and tries again to call the API, if Ok, it returns the result to the controller, if not, it just dies. The class has nothing to do with threads, because all threads call the same instance of the class

Comment: Take a step back and ask why you have multiple threads at all; IO typically does not need to be multithreaded, it just needs to be asynchronous. You can usually do all your asynchronous IO on one thread, and then you don't need to ask the question "how do I make this threadsafe?"

Comment: .net by default uses thread pool and puts concurent requests to separate threads.